# Rails form_tag remote: true processed as HTML (not */*) without 'data' hash

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have working form , which is submited with AJAX an processed correctly as '*/*'. THis one have extra confirm data hash (and need confirmation on submit).
When i want form without confirming, ale looks ok, but call is treated as HTML and fail due to missing template

One one page both form do their "stuff":

```
<h1>GOOD ajax call as */* looking for 'coupon_apply.js.erb'</h1>

        <%= form_tag(coupon_apply_path, method: :post, data: { confirm:  t('are_you_sure') }, id: 'apply-coupon', remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <label for="coupon"><%= t('coupon.coupon').capitalize %>:</label>
                <input type="text" name="coupon" id="coupon" value=""/>
              <button type="submit" value="Apply to your order" class="submit">
                <span><span><%= t('coupon.apply_order') %></span></span>
              </button>
            </div>
        <% end %>

<h1>BAD (maybe) ajax call as HTML looking for 'coupon_apply.html.erb'</h1>

        <%= form_tag(coupon_apply_path, method: :post, id: 'apply-coupon', remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <label for="coupon"><%= t('coupon.coupon').capitalize %>:</label>
               <input type="text" name="coupon" id="coupon" value=""/>
              <button type="submit" value="Apply to your order" class="submit">
                <span><span><%= t('coupon.apply_order') %></span></span>
              </button>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

The difference is only in `data: { confirm:  t('are_you_sure') },` in first form.
Both forms are rendered with data-remote="true":

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/cs/kosik/aktivovat-slevovy-kupon" data-confirm="Jste si jistí?" data-remote="true" id="apply-coupon" method="post">
 => Started POST "/cs/kosik/aktivovat-slevovy-kupon" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-24 16:38:40 +0100
 => Processing by CartController#coupon_apply as */*
```

and

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/cs/kosik/aktivovat-slevovy-kupon" data-remote="true" id="apply-coupon" method="post">
=> Started POST "/cs/kosik/aktivovat-slevovy-kupon" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-24 16:39:28 +0100
=> Processing by CartController#coupon_apply as HTML
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding format in your form:

```
 <%= form_tag(coupon_apply_path, format: :js ,method: :post, data: { confirm:  t('are_you_sure') }, id: 'apply-coupon', remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I have no trouble with form with "data" hash. This one works as expected. But the second on (without "data") do not. I tried `form_tag(coupon_apply_path, format: :js, method: :post,  id: 'apply-coupon', remote: true)`, but problem stays => `Processing by CartController#coupon_apply as HTML`

Comment: If I use `form_tag(coupon_apply_path(format: :js), method: :post,  id: 'apply-coupon', remote: true)` then request is `Processing by CartController#coupon_apply as JS`, but (correct) response  is not evaluated as script and displayed as text `('#coupon').replaceWith(...)`

Comment: If i executed returned script from JS console on original page (with form), it do what it supposed to do. So no error in JS response.

Comment: hahaha seems a bug! you could report this to rails repo I guess!